# Revealing items on hover, hide them after X seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, timeout

I'm trying to accomplish a "reveal" effect where I show items from a grid when hovering them.
Everything's OK here but once revealed I want to make them disappear again after X seconds – so it's not that when you move the mouse from the item they disappear inmediately.

That's what I tried so far but the items are not going back to their "unrevealed" state after I leave the mouse from the item.

```
var timeout;
  $(".home-box").hover(function () {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      $(this).css("opacity", 1);
  }, function () {
      timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).css("opacity", 0);
      },500);
  });
```

Does anyone have any idea about how to solve it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events and add separate functionalities in each.
The reference to `this` might be lost in the callback function passed to setTimeout.

```
$(".home-box").mouseenter(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    $(this).css("opacity", 1);
});

$(".home-box").mouseleave(function() {
    var $element = $(this)
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        $element.css("opacity", 0);
    },500);
});
```

Comment: `.hover()` is just shorthand for `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` so no need to change to these https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Agreed. But you should make your code as readable and explicit as possible. Hence I would personally go for a separate function definition.

Comment: Works perfect! I needed to remove the clearTimeout(timeout); although in order to get the desired effect. Thanks!

Comment: Basically, `clearTimeout` will make sure that if the mouse is again back on the element, the previous fading operation from `mouseleave` in call stack is not executed.

Comment: @mappie you are right! just did it :) thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Was it necessary? I used the event `mouseover` instead of the `hover`, as the `hover` will always fire when the mouse moves, even if you try to move the cursor away from the object.

```js
$(".home-box").mouseover(function () {
      $('img').css("opacity", 1);
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('img').css("opacity", 0);
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
.home-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="home-box">
  hover me pls and wait...
  <img src="https://im0-tub-ru.yandex.net/i?id=1a59e5c138260403e2230f0d2b264513&n=13">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `this` has a different meaning within the setTimeout - you can store the `box` (`this`) and reuse it.

```js
var timeout;
$(".home-box").hover(function() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  $(this).css("opacity", 1);
}, function() {
  var box = this;
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $(box).css("opacity", 0);
  }, 500);
});
```

Comment: This is how it was necessary, it turns out.. I understood the author's question a little incorrectly, and did it differently. Nice solution!

Comment: Initially, I gave you a plus, but I don't know who put a minus.

Comment: Thanks, most of my answers seem to get an *immediate* -1 regardless of the content, think someone has it in for me, but can't see who it is to think "oh, that's just x, no worries"

Comment: The same situation has touched me recently :(